# ImportError on cv2.so

Tags: python, opencv, caffe

I am trying to run fast-rcnn on a cluster, where cv2.so is not installed for public use. So I directly move the cv2.so into a PATH, but it turns as:

**/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found**

So I have to install the opencv on my local path again, this time it says:

**ImportError: /home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv11arrowedLineERNS_3MatENS_6Point_IiEES3_RKNS_7Scalar_IdEEiiid**

This really confused me, could anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little late, but I just got this same error with python 2.7 and opencv 3.1.0 on Ubuntu.  Turns out I had to reinstall `opencv-python`.  Running `sudo pip install opencv-python` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been solved by some tryings.

Since I installed under my /.~local path, it should be noticed that [include],[bin] and [lib] should all point to the local version by modifying the bashrc.

I just change the lib path while the other 2 paths remained unchanged, which point to the cluster's opencv version 2.4.9.(Mine is 2.4.11)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, but for me `PYTHONPATH` looked something like:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/opencv2.4.9/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Removing `/opt/opencv2.4.9/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` from the path provided the fix.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with the above solutions, the following one ([source](https://github.com/CharlesShang/FastMaskRCNN/issues/111)) solved my problem:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```